# jQuery: Activate/hover first tab

Tags: jquery, css

the Home-tab is selected by default but its color is grey :(

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">

    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home" data-ajax="false">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">Bla</a></li>
            <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

How can i make the tab blue? So the user can see which tab is active?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a class and style the class. That said, you haven't provided enough code for us to provide a good answer.

Comment: data-theme B will get you blue buttons

Comment: I don't want to style the first tab, it just should be blue if the tab is active (not all the time, esp. when other tabs are active).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. You need to indicate the active button with:

class="ui-btn-active and ui-state-persist"

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#home" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false" data-role="button">Bla</a></li>
     <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false" data-role="button">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

Comment: I did but the whole navbar stays grey.

Comment: I thought you wanted the buttons blue, just put the data-theme in the first div then

Comment: I'm sorry I see what you are saying! You want the selected /current one blue, I will fix the code I posted

Comment: @user3763555 sorry about that, i think current answer will help